# Create a std::vector of msgs

Tags: ros, std-msgs, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I'm trying to create a vector of a custom msg that I have declared. The msgs contains the following line:

```
float64[] LuT //where LuT is a look up table I want to publish as a msg.
```

But when I'm trying to create a std::vector of msgs like so:

```
std::vector < parse_and_pub::Lookuptable::LuT>  tables;
```

Of course including the generated header:

```
#include "parse_and_pub/Lookuptable.h"
```

I get the following errors:

```
/home/name/hydro_ws/src/parse_and_pub/src/ParseAndPub.h:32: error: ‘parse_and_pub::Lookuptable_<std::allocator<void> >::LuT’ cannot appear in a constant-expression

/home/name/hydro_ws/src/parse_and_pub/src/ParseAndPub.h:32: error: template argument 1 is invalid

/home/name/hydro_ws/src/parse_and_pub/src/ParseAndPub.h:32: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Any idea If I'm doing something wrong, or if this is intended ?

Edit: creating a:

```
std::vector < parse_and_pub::LookuptableConstPtr> tables;
```

works. But how can I access and fill this vector? tables[index].push_back() doesn't work.

Edit2: Thank you all for your answers, but it's not quite what I wanted. I tried a different approach and seems to work for now.

1. declared the vector of msgs as:

   std::vector <parse_and_pub::Lookuptable> tables;
2. populate the vectors like so:

   for(...;...;....){ //iterate the outer std::vector
   parse_and_pub::Lookuptable temp; //a temp to store the i-th look up table
   for(...;...;....){ //iterate the inner vector
   //fill the temp variable
   temp.LuT.push_back(some_value);
   }
   tables.push_back(temp);//push back the temp variable in the outer vector
   }

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205164/create-a-std::vector-of-msgs/) by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on ROS Answers with karma: 290 on 2015-03-17

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-03-17**:
Do you want to create a vector of your message or a vector of doubles? `std::vector < parse_and_pub::LookuptableConstPtr> tables;` is a vector of messages. `std::vector<double> tables` would be the equivalent to `float64[] LuT`

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-17**:
@BennyRe , thanks for answering. I want to create a vector of messages. But by using

```
 std::vector < parse_and_pub::LookuptableConstPtr> tables;
```

I don't know how to fill the message array.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To create a vector of messages use

```
std::vector < parse_and_pub::LookuptableConstPtr> tables;
```

to populate the look up table use

```
tables.at(<index>).LuT.push_back(<value>);
```

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-17**:
I did this:

```
tables.at(index_prepro).LuT.push_back(atof(token));
```

but I get the error:

```
/home/name/hydro_ws/src/parse_and_pub/src/ParseAndPub.cpp:294: error: ‘class boost::shared_ptr<const parse_and_pub::Lookuptable_<std::allocator<void> > >’ has no member named ‘LuT’
```

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-03-17**:
Use -> instead of '.'    You also need to make sure that the pointer exists already.

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-17**:
@dornhege -> doesn't work also

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your message contains an array, so you do not need to create and array your self. If you have instantiated it, it already contains the array (which for C++ is serialized as std::vector). Use it like:

```
parse_and_pub::Lookuptable your_msg_obj;  // declare message instance

// fill lookup table
for ( /* all the values you want to add */ )
{
    your_msg_obj.LuT.push_back( 12.5 /* or whatever double value */ ); 
                          //  your_msg_obj.LuT is of type std::vector<double>
                          //  just treat it like you would thread any other vector of that kind 
                          //     i. e. use .resize(), .push_back(), operator[] on it or 
                          //                   derive iterators on it as you like
}

// and publish your message with filled look up table vector
your_publisher.publish( your_msg_obj );
```

Update for your comment:

For creating an array of msgs you can do:

```
std::vector<parse_and_pub::Lookuptable> your_luts;

your_luts.resize(1);
your_luts[0].LuT.push_back( 12.5 );
```

However, you won't be able to publish such a vector (also not if you use share_ptrs to messages). If you want to publish an arrary of such look up tables you must have another message type containing an array of your lookup tables:

Your Lookuptable.msg:

```
float64[] Lut
```

Your 2nd LookuptablesArray.msg:

```
parse_and_pub/Lookuptable[] look_up_tables ## array of Lookuptable.msg
```

Then you could create an instance of `parse_and_pub::LookuptablesArray` fill that and publish that.

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-17**:
Thanks for answering Wolf. What I want to do is to create a vector of vectors (were the second vector is what you are explaining above). Alternatively I want to create a vector of msgs (where each message is a vector).
I hope it's more clear this way.

**Comment by [kokirits](https://answers.ros.org/users/21162/kokirits/) on 2015-03-18**:
Great answer Wolf, I didn't even know about publishing a msg like:

```
parse_and_pub/Lookuptable[] look_up_tables ## array of Lookuptable.msg
```